# Mathematical Formula - Variable Substitution with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a Javascript function that evaluates a user-entered string as a mathematical formula.

For example, the user may type in `1 + 1`, and the function will evaluate it to `2`. I'm using a library to do this, so the math and syntax is handled for that already. However, I have variables that the user can reference. The user can create a number variable, give it a name (of their choosing), and reference it in the equation. Assume the user writes `1 + counter`, the math eval library obviously doesn't know what `counter` is, so I am using regular expressions to pre-process the formula. The preprocessing function will see `counter`, lookup its value, and replace it with the literal. So if the user had set `counter` to 3 elsewhere, my function will take `1 + counter`, replace counter with `3` to get `1 + 3`, and then send the formula to the math evaluation library.

The issue I'm having is writing a function that processes this using regular expressions.
I'm starting with the regular expression `([^A-Za-z0-9])counter($|[^A-Za-z0-9])`, which matches `counter` only if there is NOT another alphanumeric character on either side of it. For example, the user may type in `counter2` at some point, and I want to make sure that `counter2` is looked up, but that `counter` would not match. Secretely, to improve performance, I actually loop through variables, generate regular expressions for them, and match them that way. Some may not match at all, but it runs in O(n) rather than having to search through a list of variables for every reference in the array. In other words, I don't build a syntax tree or anything, so if I had the variables `counter` and `counter2`, I would generate regex for each and try to match them, hence if the formula was `counter2`, the function still tries a match for `counter` and `counter2`, but only `counter2` should match.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```js
var re = new RegExp(`(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])${variableName}($|[^A-Za-z0-9])`, "g");

let match = re.exec(formula);

while (match !== null) {
  // If "+counter+" is matched, I have to make sure that the +'s remain, hence replacing on the match
  var sub = match[0].replace(`${variableName}`, `{${variableValue}}`);

  formula = formula.replace(match[0], sub)

  re.lastIndex = 0; // just reset to the start for now
  match = re.exec(formula);
}

// Pass to math library next
```

This works in most cases but I have the following issue:
For the formula `counter+counter`, only the first `counter+` matches, when both should match.

So, what I need is basically regular expression/function that does the following:

- Take a variable name
- Replace all occurences of it as long as the occurences don't have a alphanumeric character in front or back. So if I'm matching `counter` against a formula, `+counter+` would match (+ aren't alphanumeric), `+ counter` would match (space isn't alphanumeric), but `counter2` wouldn't match, because it's a different variable name entirely, and 2 is alphanumeric.

Any ideas? I'm trying to do this the right way, I imagine there can be many unknown side effects if I don't do this correctly.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is typical. Use a lookahead - ``var re = new RegExp(`(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])${variableName}(?=$|[^A-Za-z0-9])`, "g"); formula = formula.replace(re, "$1"+variableValue)``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a lookahead at the end, `(?=$|[^A-Za-z0-9])` instead of a `($|[^A-Za-z0-9])` capturing group, and shrink the code to a greater extent if you just use `replace`:

```
var re = new RegExp(`(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])${variableName}(?=\$|[^A-Za-z0-9])`, "g");
formula = formula.replace(re, "$1"+variableValue)
```

Note the `$1` in the replacement part is the backreference to the value stored in Group 1, that is, start of string or any char but an ASCII alphanumeric (captured with `(^|[^A-Za-z0-9])`).